# What is the easiest way to subset 'every other bits' in C/C++?

Tags: c++

For example,

```
unsigned char a = 0b11010010;
```

I want to subset `a` for every other bits and put them together to make a four-bit value, i.e., taking `0`, `2`, `4`, `6`th position and place them into `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`rd position.

It can be hard-coded as follows:

```
unsigned char subset =  (a & (1 << 0))       |
                       ((a & (1 << 2)) >> 1) |
                       ((a & (1 << 4)) >> 2) |
                       ((a & (1 << 6)) >> 3);
```

I want to know if there is more easier, simpler or elegant way for doing this.

Comment: 3th? Thirth? That doesn't look right :-)

Comment: Oh, yes... Thank you. Fixed it.

Comment: Well, no problem. But I want to know if I am doing a sort of 'reinventing a wheel', or doing somewhat inefficient (in either readability or performance).

Comment: in fact you can't subset bits because they are not addressable. the alternative is to use an array of 8 chars then do masking storing each bit value as a single byte

Answer (score 1):

The code you have is the clearest expression of your intent, and the most amenable to any possible compiler optimisations (and as a function, you could declare it `constexpr`).  You could do some clever masking and multiplication by magic numbers - but I'm not even going to derive those numbers because the gain is outweighed by the unmaintainability!

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not elegant, and would expand to what you just wrote, but can't hate templates can we?

```
template <int pos = 0>
struct altbit{
  static char compute(char a) {
    return ((a & (1 << (2*pos))) >> pos) | altbit<pos+1>::compute(a);
  }
};

template <>
struct altbit<4> {
  static char compute (char a) {
    return 0;
  }
};
```

Usage: `altbit<>::compute(a)`

Comment: `constexpr` anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) can make bit operations more elegant:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    std::bitset<8> b1(0b11010010);
    std::bitset<4> b2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        b2[i] = b1[i*2];
    }
    std::cout << std::hex << "in: " << b1 << ", out: " << b2 << "\n";
}
```